# C# Linq - Issue with joining3 tables - Error CS1941

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to fetch the records based on this query

```
  documentList = await (from doc in _dbContext.Documents
                                      join doce in _dbContext.StudentEnrollments on doc.ID equals doce.ID
                                      join enr in _dbContext.Enrollments on doce.EnrollmentID equals enr.Id
                                      where enr.name != null
                                      && (enr.faiedlattemps = 1 || enr.ReferenceNumber != null)
                                      select doc);
```

I am getting the

> "Correlates the elements of two sequences based on matching key error. The default equality comparer is used to compare keys"

I tried with this as well

```
var result = from x in _dbContext.Documents
                             join y in _dbContext.StudentEnrollments
                             on new { X1 = x.ID } equals new { X1 = y.ID}
                             join z in _dbContext.Enrollments on new { Z1 = y.EnrollmentID } equals new { Z1 = z.Id}
                             select new
                             {
                                 /// Columns
                             };
```

Getting the same error

Comment: Maybe it is better to start by showing your classes?

Comment: "Correlates the elements of two sequences based on matching key" That's not the error, this seems to be the summary of of the `Join` method. This is the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1941 So it seems that your IDs have different types.

Comment: Or, you could just tell EF about how your objects relate, then you can say `_dbContext.Documents.Include(d => d.StudentEnrollments).ThenInclude(se => se.Enrollment)`